# Unity Custom Editor Window Input Control for Type Determined by Reflection

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, reflection, editor, imgui

I am creating a GUI for selecting a function in a Unity custom **EditorWindow** inspired by the **UnityEvent** GUI. I can't get **UnityEvent** itself to work; using a **EditorGUILayout.PropertyField** and referencing the **UnityEvent** member as a serialized property produces an empty foldout.

I have choosing a function working, but I can't figure out how to allow the user to specify the function parameter arguments.

```
using System.Reflection;
int functionIndex = 0;
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(LvlGenFunctions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
string methodNames = new string[methods.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < methods.Length; ++i)
{
  methodNames[i] = methods[i].Name;
}
functionIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(functionIndex, methodNames);
methods[functionIndex].Invoke(null, null);
```

I can get the **ParameterInfo** and thus the **ParameterType**, but I don't know how to create an input GUI field to specify an appropriate parameter argument.

How can I create a Unity IMGUI input field for a parameter whose type is determined by reflection?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear

`EditorWindow : ScriptableObject` and `ScriptableObject : Object`

`SerializedObject` work with `UnityEngine.Object` so you can use this constructor:

```
new SerializedObject(Object target);
```

**`EditorWindow`**

```
public UnityEvent OnSomeEvent;
private SerializedObject serializedObject;
private SerializedProperty property;

private void OnEnable()
{
    serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this);
    property = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(OnSomeEvent));
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property, true);
}
```

Now you have the inspector but it's not something that you want.

---

Problem is it`s too ugly.

Update your code like below:

```
public UnityEvent OnSomeEvent;
private SerializedObject serializedObject;
private SerializedProperty property;
// new fields
private UnityEventDrawer EventDrawer;
private GUIContent Content;

private void OnEnable()
{
    serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this);
    property = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(OnSomeEvent));
    // new initialization
    EventDrawer = new UnityEventDrawer();
    Content = new GUIContent(property.displayName, property.tooltip);
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    // new drawer
    var eventHeigth = EventDrawer.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
    var rect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(true, eventHeigth);
    EventDrawer.OnGUI(rect, property, label);
}
```